# Why do i have so many processes spawned with the same name?

Tags: ubuntu, process, cpu-usage

How come so many processes exist with the same name for basically every application on my system? Spotify, Firefox and other apps all do this and sometimes opening a few additional tabs means that my 16-core computer's fan starts revving like a plane taking off. Do i have something misconfigured or are these normal?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at are multiple tasks of the same process. This is expected behavior as they can be processed in parallel.

[relevant Stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145318/multiple-processes-with-the-same-name)